# making vim ' % ' command more useful in verilog type code

Tags: vim, vi, verilog

In `VIM` `%` is an excellent time saving command. 
I work in verilog and it does not have much use of brackets. So I wanted to know is there any mechanism through which I can use `%` effectively in verilog.

For example :

1. If my cursor is under word `task` and I give `%` command it takes me to the line where we have `endtask`.
2. Similarly for `module` to `endmodule` and `begin` to `end`.

This kind of feature can be really helpful while we are looking at large verilog modules and functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Activate the matchit plugin. It's part of Vim's distribution but it's not activated by default. The instructions are here: `:help matchit-install`.

I don't think that verilog is supported but it's relatively easy to add new definitions. See `:help matchit-newlang` for details.

Comment: `:help matchit-newlang` gives `E149: Sorry, no help for matchit-newlang `

Comment: Have a look at [this example](http://thetinkerer.blogspot.com/2009/02/matchitvims-bmatchwords-for-template.html) for extending matchit for some of perl's template toolkit directives.

Comment: @nav_jean, it works if you activate the matchit plugin as demonstrated in `:help matchit-install`.